# Using scanner with xml

Tags: java, hashmap

I have,

`1.` I  have an xml file consists of individuals info.

`2.` Hash map that reads the xml-file.

`3.` `Scanner` that lets the user gives an individual name(just the name), so that code compare with the information stored in the has map if i matches ant then then the code prints that individual information(name, phone etc).

I face an issue with the looping part, can you help to get to work ?

From my Main class:

```
System.out.println("Please enter a name:");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Person c1 = new Person();
c1.setName(scan.nextLine());
String value = c1.getName();
c1.getTimeInfo(value);
```

From my Person class:

```
 public void getPersonInfo(String value)
 {

 List<Person> t = persons.get(name);
 int iD ;
 value = t.get(0);
 for(int i = 0; i < t.length(); ++i) {
 if(t.get(i) == value) {
  value = t.get(i);
        this.iD = i;
    }

 System.out.println("The person info : " + this.name.get(iD) + "-"      +this.phone.get(iD) + " "+ this.address.get(iD)+ "-" + this.title,get(iD));
```

Comment: Where and how are you using the hashmap?

Comment: `List<Person> t = persons.get(name);` where does `name` come from? Should it be `value`?  I don't see a `HashMap` or a `Map` of any kind in your code — you're using a `List`.  You are using a `Scanner` to get an input value, not to get a value from a map (or from a list)

Comment: You can't use a Scanner on a HashMap, and you can't read XML with a HashMap. Please reword your quezon so it makes some sense.

Comment: Sorry if the current code isn't clear enough, i just added my full actual code. –

Comment: My remarks are addressed to your text, not your code.

Answer (score 0):

The way your `getPersonInfo()` method functions now is to return the last person in the names list. This is because you reassign the input value to `t.get(0)`, and then loop through the list. This will result in the last name always being returned. You can do without having a variable for this comparison, as you don't use it in your output. Also, you should never use `==` for comparing strings, use `.equals()` instead, like so:

```
public void getPersonInfo(String value){

    List<Person> t = persons.get(name);
    int iD ;
    for(int i = 0; i < t.length(); ++i) {
        if(t.get(i).equals(value)) {
            this.iD = i;
         }
         System.out.println("The person info : " + this.name.get(iD) + "-"      +this.phone.get(iD)
    }
}
```

This still does not prevent nothing from happening if the input value is not in the name list, so you may want to take care of that case. However, this will prevent you from always printing the information about the last person in the names list.

Also, you are comparing a `Person` to a string in the if- statement in the for loop, so either change the input to a `Person` or the list of people to a list of strings.